# Cypress get wrong field in some case

Tags: cypress

Running my tests with Cypress I see a strange error happening when I try to write in a specific field.
In my case, I want to write in an autocomplete field but Cypress for some reason select another field that does not have the same selector.

This is the field I want to write in.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    #triggerLastName="matAutocompleteTrigger" 
    (blur)="hideSearchContactHint()"
    (focus)="showSearchContactHint()"
    (keydown)="onKeydown($event)"
    [formControl]="contactSearchField"
    [matAutocomplete]="customerAuto"
    autocomplete="off"
    matInput
    data-cy="contactSearchAutocomplete"
    type="search"/>
```

And this is the line in the test:

```
        cy.get('[data-cy=contactSearchAutocomplete]').type('test');
```

And this is the field selected by cypress

```
     <input
       (blur)="hideSearchProduct();syncModelWithForm(i);"
       (focus)="showSearchProduct(i)"
       (keydown)="onF9Pressed($event, i)"
       (keydown.Enter)="searchProductByBarcode(getFormRow[i].controls['productSku'].value, i)"
       (keydown.Tab)="searchProductByBarcode(getFormRow[i].controls['productSku'].value, i)"
       [formControl]="getFormRow[i].controls['productSku']"
       autocomplete="off"
       class="form-control"
       id="{{ 'code' + i }}"
       style="width: 120px!important;"
       type="search"/>
```

As you can see in the image Cypress selects the field where you read 'test' instead of the field on top.
[image]

Comment: May be you want to correct the typo error with the selector `"contactSearchAutocomplete"`. And let us know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to write in this field, can you tell me the typo error?

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, could you share a minimal repo where I can play with it? Is it possible?

Comment: Hi unfortunately I can't share the repo but if it helps I can share the code I am testing and maybe a video?

Comment: Ok, please try this: if you export the markup in a plain HTML file and you run the test (or, better, just the element selection and the typing), does Cypress select the right input element or the wrong one?

Comment: @NoriSte Ok I can try, here you can find the code and the video.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OZDkLARx0WvTICdZQwdj6FmVa8THU8Pu

Comment: Reading the comments, it seems that both the tests work if they're the "first one" or the "only one", is it right? If you put them in two different files do they work? Recently I've seen more than one error similar to yours...

Comment: @NoriSte Ok now  I have 2 different files with 1 test each one and only the first test pass

Comment: Could you raise an issue on the [Cypress project](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues) please? Thank you!!

Comment: @Alessandro did you reported the issue on the Cypress repo? I'd like to add some notes of mines 

Comment: @NoriSte just opened
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5858